# How to get props value to be used in emits array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I got a console error when I tried to list custom event in the component's emits option like this:

**PARENT**

```
<Btn
   event-name="toggleSideMenu"
   @toggle-side-menu="toggleHandler">
        toggle
 </Btn>
```

**CHILD**

```
<template>
   <button @click="handleClick">
      <slot></slot>
   </button>
</template>

export default {
   props: {
      eventName: {
         type: String,
         default: ''
      }
   },
   emits: [this.eventName], // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventName' of undefined
   methods: {
      handleClick() {
          this.$emit(this.eventName)
      }
   }
}
```

How is the correct way to get this thing to work?

Comment: remove this. from emits array.

Comment: got similar error: Failed to compile. error  'eventName' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: What about `emits: {this.eventName: null}` ?

Comment: Please share your emit code and parent element, which is listening to the eventName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do that.

You may need to find a way to get around this. You can still emit an event without defining it in the `emits` array, but you end up losing some of the benefits.

There is an [RFC/proposal](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/issues/204) for doing just that, but doesn't look like it's going anywhere.